pam.d with MFA skips public-key authentication
I have a pam.d configuration with MFA authentication on a test server.
I noticed that the IP addresses that are in file access-without-MFA.conf mentioned,
can login without password and without private public-key.
The expected result that IP addresses in access-without-MFA.conf file would not need MFA but still need Public/Private Key or password to login.
I have tried to change places and put the list bellow but in this case, every login requires password and ignores public-key.
ssh-copy-id did not help.
This is not allowing any automation.
#%PAM-1.0
#
# skip one-time password for special hosts
auth [success=done default=ignore] pam_access.so accessfile=/etc/security/access-without-MFA.conf
#
auth        requisite   pam_nologin.so
auth        include     common-auth
account     requisite   pam_nologin.so
account     include     common-account
password    include     common-password
session     required    pam_loginuid.so
session     include     common-session
session     optional    pam_lastlog.so   silent noupdate showfailed

# skip one-time password for special hosts
#auth [success=done default=ignore] pam_access.so accessfile=/etc/security/access-without-MFA.conf
#
# one time password required
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so echo_verification_code
#

access-without-MFA.conf
- test-vm login without pwd
+ : ALL : 10.xx.xx.xx
#
+ : ALL : LOCAL
- : ALL : ALL


Intricacies of PAM are always a bit tricky for me, but success=done is "equivalent to ok with the side effect of terminating the module stack and PAM immediately returning to the application."    if accessfile=/etc/security/access-without-MFA.conf returns PAM_SUCCESS  and therefore won't process anything else anymore - I think you might need to move the line containing pam_access.so to just before line with pam_google_authenticator.so  - But when you use ssh with PAM and pam grants access, it won't need process public keys anymore

hi, i tried it.  You can see at the end of the file. In this case i am asked for the password every time i need to login. The public key exchange is ignored. For automation, if public-key exchange was successful than it should login without password.
